# How can I move file into Recycle Bin / trash on different platforms using PyQt4?

Tags: python, qt4, cross-platform, pyqt4, recycle-bin

I would like to add the next feature to my cross-platform PyQt4 application: when user selects some file and select "remove" action on it that file will be moved to Recycle Bin folder instead of being permantly removed. I think I can find Windows-specific solution using Win32 API or something similar, but I'd like to know does similar operation could be executed on Ubuntu/Linux and MaxOSX as well via PyQt4 methods.

Comment: For those who find this question and are using **PyQt5** rather than PyQt4: In Qt 5.15 the [`QFile.moveToTrash` function](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfile.html#moveToTrash) was added ([announcement](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/whatsnew515.html#qt-core-module)). I hope this help!

Answer (score 79, accepted):

It's a good thing you're using Python, I created a library to do just that a while ago:

http://www.hardcoded.net/articles/send-files-to-trash-on-all-platforms.htm

On PyPI: [Send2Trash](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Send2Trash)

**Installation**

Using conda:

```
conda install Send2Trash
```

Using pip:

```
pip install Send2Trash
```

**Usage**

Delete file or folders

```
from send2trash import send2trash
send2trash("directory")
```

Comment: New ctypes-based version of your library looks very handy. Thanks

Comment: This is awesome. On OS X it works with the 'Put Back' option (when right clicking a file in the trash). Thanks!

Comment: This should be added to the standard library. Does anyone know the proper mechanism for making that sort of proposal? I wrote something up at bugs.python.org, but I don't feel like that's the proper place to do it: http://bugs.python.org/issue24185

Comment: it also sends folders to trash

Comment: conda install Send2Trash

Comment: 'pip install Send2Trash' raises an alarm from the virus scanner complaining that the package contains a trojan.

Comment: thanks. would be nice if it supported forward slashes `/` in Windows to make cross platform coding easier

Answer (score 2):

I guess there really is no cross-platform solution provided by Qt and it's not a totally trivial task to implement the trash concept in Linux since it's slightly different based on which file manager is in use.

Here's a site discussing the trash concept in [Nautilus](http://developer.gnome.org/doc/whitepapers/nautilus/nautilus-internals.html) and another one for [KDE](http://www.raiden.net/articles/inside_kde_-_the_trash_system/).

Under Windows you can use the Win32 API like you said. [Python solution available here](http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/37113-recycle-bin-python).

Mac OS X puts the trashed files in ~/.Trash similar to other *NIX OSes, but I couldn't quickly Google any documentation for it. It seems that the OS X trash info file is some kind of binary format and not plain text like in Linux.

Symbian doesn't have a desktop concept and thus no trashcan concept either. It might be similar for other mobile platforms.

EDIT: [Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/108301/deleting-a-single-file-from-the-trash-in-mac-os-x-snow-leopard) has some discussion revealing that .DS_Store does indeed store information about trashed files, but no specifics about the format.

Answer (score 1):

The [best OSX solution](http://www.anthonysmith.me.uk/2008/01/08/moving-files-to-trash-from-the-mac-command-line/) I know uses Applescript. I did not, however, invent it, so I shall simply link to it here.

It would be nice to have a module that packaged up the Win32/KDE/OSX solutions into one, i feel, and imported the correct one on demand. Is that how you solved your problem in the end?